# Enterprise Samba fileserver management

Tags: windows, samba, graphical-user-interface

Can anyone recommend a gui (webbased or windows) to manage a samba fileserver (active directory integration, smbcquotas,...)?

Answer (score 1):

[SWAT](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/SWAT.html) is the official web based tool from SAMBA. Can't comment on how good or bad it is as I don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL (and it's variants) come with system-config-samba which does a pretty decent job of managing Samba shares, and it works even better if you use SWAT to setup the who Samba installation

Answer (score 0):

http://gadmintools.flippedweb.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=16&Itemid=30

you can try above link!!

Answer (score 0):

There are many [listed on the samba website](http://samba.org/samba/GUI/) .

I cannot recommend one over the other as our samba setup is so minimal I just edited the configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) is a web based config / monitor tool for Linux. It uses perl, so should run out the box on most distros. It has samba modules, and many more.
But if you make up a lot of shares then it may be worth you learning the share syntax of shares in the the smb.conf file.